# Why new is called 3 times and delete is called 3 times?

Tags: c++

I have a simple program where I am trying to do operator overloading for new and delete.

Just for trying, I did operator overloading for new and delete in global scope apart from class scope.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<<"\n\nGlobal scope new:\n";
   void * ptr = malloc(size);
   return ptr;
}

void operator delete(void *ptr)
{
    cout<<"\n\nGlobal scope delete:\n";
    free(ptr);

}

  class test
  {

      public:
     int age;
     string name;

test(string str, int a)
{
    age = a;
    name = str;
}
 void display();   
 };

 void test::display()
 {
    cout<<"\n\nname is:-"<<name<<"  and age is :- "<<age<<endl;
 }


int main()
  {

  test *t = new test("sanjeev",29);
  if(t!=NULL)
  cout<<"\n\nMemory allocated:"<<endl;
  t->display();
   delete t;
 }
```

Now on executing this program I am seeing that new is called 3 times and delete is called 3 times.

[image]

If I declare new and delete operator overloading inside class only one time call to new and delete is happening.

What is the reason behind this flow?

Comment: Then now what is your problem? Is it the fact new and delete are called three times when you are using new yourself only once in the main?

Comment: problem is why 3 times call is happening, it should happen one time, if i declare this operator overloading inside class , only one time call is happening

Comment: Avoid images in your question. Your image contains text, show it as formatted text (four spaces at start of every line). Also, compile your code with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Run it step by step in a debugger. Take a week to read a good C++ programming book.

Comment: So what is the question? Since you overloaded the *global* operators, you intercepted all calls, including the ones made by other code, like standard library code. *You* are explicitly making only one call, but there are plenty of other calls.

Comment: If you just want it to call once then you should consider overriding new in your base class

Comment: @Ant  can you please explain it in more detail... as i am new to c++

Comment: @user5794230 You have globally overridden operator new that's why std::string calls to new will call your new too. Like I said, if you don't want this to happen then you should consider overriding new in your base class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string` ultimately uses the global `operator new`. You're creating two `std::string`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should override operator new in your base class if you don't want new to be called multiple times in this case:

```
class CBaseTest
{
public:
    void *operator new(const size_t allocation_size)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nMy new invoked:\n";
        return ::malloc(allocation_size);
    }

    void operator delete(void *block_of_memory)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nMy delete invoked:\n";
        ::free(block_of_memory);
    }
};

class test : public CBaseTest
{
public:
    int age;
    string name;

    test(string str, int a)
    {
        age = a;
        name = str;
    }
    void display();
};

void test::display()
{
    cout << "\n\nname is:-" << name << "  and age is :- " << age << endl;
}
```

Here

```
test *t = new test("sanjeev", 29);
```

will invoke your new method.

Similarly,

```
delete t;
```

will invoke your delete method

Now, if you try to allocate memory using new for your class test or any classes derived from CBaseTest then your new will be called.